# Why does a centered HTML DIV move depending on its content?

Tags: css, html

I have a div with the following css class applied:

```
div.centralcolumn
{
   width: 90%;
   max-width: 720px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   font-size: 80%;  
   font-family: verdana, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
   line-height: 1.6em;
   text-align: left;
}
```

It centers because the auto margins evenly divide the remaining space between both sides. However, one of my pages draws the div slightly further to the left than the others. Upon inspection the divs are the same width (720px) and if I modify the content then the problem div moves back to the correct position. The content in question is a list item, here's the actual block of html:

```
    <p>
      <a href="http://ucf.academia.edu/SebastianRisi/Papers/842358/Task_Switching_in_Multirobot_Learning_through_Indirect_Encoding">
        <strong>Task Switching in Multirobot Learning through Indirect Encoding</strong>
      </a><br/>David B. D'Ambrosio, Joel Lehman, Sebastian Risi, and Kenneth O. Stanley (2011).
      <br />
      <strong>In: Proceedings of the International Conference on Intelligent Robots and Systems (IROS 2011 San Fransisco, CA)</strong>
    </p>
```

That last line of text seems to be the culprit. If I shorten it then the problem goes away, I tried inserting a 
 to stop the text reaching the edge of the div but that had no effect. BTW I'm using Chrome and Firefox, both exhibit the problem.

Comment: Are scrollbars appearing for the page that is slightly off, and not on the others?

Comment: Ha! Thanks. Yes there is a scroll bar. So the question becomes - how do I compensate for it thus keeping the div the same distance from the left edge?

Comment: Only way around it is to always force the scrollbar to appear: http://ryanfait.com/resources/forcing-vertical-scrollbars/

Comment: @JohnKeyes: Just wondering: Why dont we use html {overflow-y:scroll} instead of the 1px margin at the bottom? Is there a specific reason?

Comment: @Andrej it's been a while since I tested any of this stuff, but there were multi-browser issues with some approaches. If `overflow-y` works in all browsers for this scenario, then that is a preferable solution IMO.

Comment: maybe you have some more css that tell the `p` block to nowrap? take that and the words will wrap correctly and the width will be retained.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making the max-width by 40px bigger at first. If it seems too wide, then shorten in by 10px and so on till it's perfect width for you.